# How to send a message to a comment author on a Facebook page post using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If person comments a post on a Facebook page admin of this page can see a button to send a private message to this user.

How to send a message to a comment author using Facebook API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`{object-id}/private_replies`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/object/private_replies) endpoint is what you're looking for.

> This edge allows Pages to reply to Post Comments and Visitor Posts with a private Message. It can be used with the following nodes:
>
> - Comment
> - Post